# Getting error in inserting a record in sqlite3 using vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector, sqlite

I am working on a project for my Unix class. So as you can see from my code, I create functions to read a text file and parse the text file so that I may store the string values into a vector.

After storing the values into a vector, I use that vector to insert the records into my database. For some reason, I am not able to insert my vector and I receive this error:

**error**: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type
      'std::__1::basic_string'
    sql = "INSERT INTO ARTIST(ID, NAME) " \

Here is a snippet of my code:

---

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  { 
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    char *sql;

    // initialize all text files
    ifstream artistFile("artist.txt"); //Input file
    ifstream cd("cd.txt");
    ifstream track("track.txt");

    //string sqlArtistInsert;
    string sqlCDInsert;
    string sqlTrackInsert;

    std::vector<std::string> artistVector;
    artistVector = readFile(artistVector, artistFile);

    createArtistTable();

   // Open database 
   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      exit(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }


   // Create SQL statement 
    sql = "INSERT INTO ARTIST(ID, NAME) " \
    "VALUES(" + artistVector[0] + "," + artistVector[1] +"); " \
    "VALUES(" + artistVector[2] + "," + artistVector[3] +"); " \
    "VALUES(" + artistVector[4] + "," + artistVector[5] +"); " \
    "VALUES(" + artistVector[6] + "," + artistVector[7] + ");";


// Execute SQL statement
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
  }
```

For some reason, it says that the error is at the

```
  sql = insert
      ^
```

Also, the text file I'm parsing and storing it the vector is this below:

```
1|Pink Floyd      //artistVector[0] & artistVector[1]
2|Genesis        //artistVector[2] & artistVector[3]
3|Einaudi       //artistVector[4] & artistVector[5]
4|Melanie C     //artistVector[6] & artistVector[7]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
// Create SQL statement 
sql = "INSERT INTO ARTIST(ID, NAME) VALUES(";
sql += artistVector[0];
sql += ',';
sql += artistVector[1];
sql += ");";
```

but note the following:

- the `sql` variable should be defined as a `std::string`.  If, later, you need a `const char *`, use the `c_str()` member function to get it.  You can't concatenate `const char *` variables.
- Using `+=` avoids creating temporary variables when you have multiple concatenations of `std:string` variables so it's more efficient.

<s>- I don't think you can insert multiple records at once.  I think it's invalid SQL but check this.</s>

- It's probably more efficient to make an sql string that has variable place holders and use bind instead of constructing sql strings as you are doing.

Comment: That's what I did, now I'm getting an error that says:
SQL error: near "Floyd": syntax error


I'm assuming it's whenever I parsed the data? Not sure... But each index in the vector goes as this:
    artistVector[0] = 1
    artistVector[1] = Pink Floyd
    artistVector[2] = 2
    artistVector[3] = Genesis
    artistVector[4] = 3
artistVector[5] = Einaudi
artistVector[6] = 6
artistVector[7] = Melanie C 

It says that it's failing near Floyd. Maybe due to the next line? Not sure. 

On the exact text file it shows:

Comment: @BarcodePiglet Edit you original question and show your exact code and compiler error.  Otherwise it very hard to figure it out.